# Run Class Continuously on Deployment

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a [listener project](http://java-by-ash.blogspot.com/2012/07/continuous-directory-listener.html) that I would like to implement a web-version of. I need it to run continuously upon deployment. In other words, as soon as the application has been deployed onto **Apache Tomcat 7.0.14.0** it should start listening/running immediately and continuously without affecting the rest of the web application. Is this possible?

Comment: you mean a `ServletContextListener`?

Comment: yes, but it it possible to have it run in the background? If you try and run index.jsp, it will only open in the browser after `contextInitialized` processes are complete (Even if you run the processes in a `new Thread()`.

Comment: that doesn't not true - if you run in a separate thread, the contextInitialized method will return and everything will continue as normal

Comment: `Thead.sleep` is a static method, so when you call `th.sleep()` you're not actually telling `th` to sleep, but the current thread. Hence the loop takes 3 seconds. The compiler is probably warning you about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, it appears Tomcat expects the ServletContext listener to complete, before moving on to the next stage of deployment. In that case you could put the work you wish to happen in the background into a Runnable class.

**RunClassOnDeployment.java**

```
package web.deployment;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class RunClassOnDeployment implements Runnable {

    ServletContext myServletContext; // in case you need the servelet context

    RunClassOnDeployment(ServletContext sc) {
           myServletContext = sc;
    }

    public void run() {
       Thread th = new Thread();
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                th.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread interrupted! " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

and set that off using an ExecutorService within your listener:

**MyListener.java**

```
package web.deployment;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(new RunClassOnDeployment(arg0.getServletContext()));
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>web.deployment.MyListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

[Download](http://java-by-ash.blogspot.com/2012/07/threads-in-java-web-application.html) the example

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start your Thread

```
 @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        Thread th = new Thread();
....
th.start();
}
```

But the solution with the ExecutorService is quiet better!

And... You'll should auto-start your application, if you want.

```
<load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
```